# Finding out a Windows login account name used for SQL connection using TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, authentication

I wonder if it is possible to find out a Windows account details like user name that user used to connect to SQL server DB through Windows Authentication connection? 
I have a table that has a UserName  column and I would like to select the rows that have the UserName value the same as the login account name. Is it possible to write a stored procedure or function something like this

SELECT * from MyTable where MyTable.UserName =

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SYSTEM_USER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx):

"If the current user is logged in to SQL Server by using Windows Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the Windows login identification name in the form: DOMAIN\user_login_name. However, if the current user is logged in to SQL Server by using SQL Server Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the SQL Server login identification name, such as WillisJo for a user logged in as WillisJo."